# SQL*Loader: Insert linked data into multiple tables

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I would like to use SQL*Loader to load data into two tables in parent-child relationship using IDs from sequence. Is it possible? Example:

---

**Input file:**

```
HDR|first batch
DAT|first element of first batch
DAT|second element of first batch
HDR|second batch
DAT|first element of second batch
```

**Required result:**

Table HDR:

```
HDR_ID|title
1     |first batch
2     |second batch
```

Table DAT (HDR_ID being foreign key):

```
DAT_ID|HDR_ID|content
1     |1     |first element of first batch
2     |1     |second element of first batch
3     |2     |first element of second batch
```

---

My main goal here is to let SQL*Loader / Oracle take care of ID sequences for me and link them properly.

If it is possible using direct load then even better.

Answer (score 0):

You could load to a view, using an INSTEAD OF trigger to provide the required logic.

Alternatively, you could use an external table combined with a multi-table insert statement to do the job.

Comment: How do I perform multi-table insert which creates the link?